# Laravel migrations find which migration fails

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

So when you run `php artisan migrate` and it fails, it gives you the errors in the terminal.

Is there a way to see which migration file causes the error? I want to get the filename of that migration.

Comment: may be, you should check `laravel.log` file

Comment: You can check for tables as well which table has been created last, the next 
 migration file would be causing error

Comment: @MilanChheda you can post your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for errors, you should look at `laravel.log` file.

Answer (score 7):

You can see the full trace by adding the flag `-vvv` so you can identify the file and the exact line.

```
php artisan migrate -vvv
```

It will print the same error as `laravel.log` file

Answer (score 4):

You can run `php artisan migrate:status` to see which migrations have run and which haven't.

The last non-run migration will be the one that has failed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see any errors occurs during debugging, just look into `laravel.log` file.

- Log files are in `storage/logs` folder. `laravel.log` is the default filename. If there is a permission issue with the log folder, Laravel just halts. So if your endpoint generally works - permissions are not an issue.
- Ensure debug mode is on - either add `APP_DEBUG=true` to `.env` file or set an environment variable

Hope this helps you!!